# Difference between dependent and independent group designs

Tags: t-test

It seems to make common sense that a dependent (repeated measures) design would yield a lower critical value for t than an independent sample design since in the former variance *should* be lower. Yet when I run the two different t-tests in Excel using the same data I get a lower critical value for t using the independent t-test.

Am I missing something or do I just need more coffee?

Comment: Since this is about a t-test, you need more tea, not coffee ;-)

Comment: I don't follow you. I'm not actually asking about one design versus another. I'm really just trying to get a handle on the math. The question, in other words, was more of a thought experiment.

Comment: Then see especially he last note at the end of my Answer. There are fundamental differences between two-sample designs and paired designs, but comparing critical values is not how to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology 'repeated measures' has come to be used to mean so many different things in various fields of application that I prefer different terminology.
Let's look at fundamental differences between a paired t design and analysis
and a two-sample t (independent samples) design and analysis. The quick answer
is that the paired design controls variability.

**Two independent samples.** Suppose $n = 25$ observations are randomly sampled from each of two normal populations, with distributions $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1 = 80, \sigma = 5)$ and $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_2 = 82, \sigma = 5),$ respectively. 
We test $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ against $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2.$

*Test:* The test statistic in this case amounts to $T = \frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2}{S_p\sqrt{2/25}},$ where
$S_p = \sqrt{(S_1^2 + S_2^2)/2}.$ We reject $H_0$ at the 5% level for $|T| > 2.011.$

```
qt(.975, 48)
[1] 2.010635
```

Intuitively, the issue is whether we can detect the slight difference between
$\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ through the random 'fog' represented by $\sigma = 5.$

```
qt(.975, 48)
[1] 2.010635
```

*With data:* To see how this works in practice, we generate fake data that matches the
specific alternative $H_a: \mu_1 - \mu_2 = -2 \ne 0.$ [Computations in R.]

```
set.seed(918);  x1 = round(rnorm(25, 80, 5));  x2 = round(rnorm(25, 82, 5))
x1
[1] 80 89 82 81 90 90 72 77 74 81 81 67 83 76 78 80 69 84 78 76 82 81 78 84 94
x2
[1] 85 83 82 77 80 89 84 74 82 77 82 78 82 79 81 81 94 75 83 79 85 83 78 75 91
summary(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  67.00   77.00   81.00   80.28   83.00   94.00 
[1] 6.360818
summary(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  74.00   78.00   82.00   81.56   83.00   94.00 
[1] 4.839766
```

[image]

A pooled 2-sample t test on these samples, using `t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T)`,
returns $T = -.0801,$ which has $|T| < 2.011,$ so that we cannot reject $H_0.$
[The P=value is 0.402 > 0.05, which also indicates we cannot reject.]

*Discussion:* So in this particular case, we have not been able to detect a difference
$|\mu_1 - \mu_2| = 2.$  Nor are these two particularly unlucky samples: 
one can show that such data would lead to rejection in about 28% of cases
so generated. The observations in vectors `x1` and `x2` are independent;
their correlation is only about $r = 9.12,$ consistent with independence.
Each sample comes form a population with standard deviation $\sigma = 5,$ and
the variances add.
The estimate of the difference $\bar X_1 - \bar X_2$ is estimated by the denominator of the t statistic, for our sample about 1.60.

**Paired data.** By contrast, suppose we have $n = 25$ subjects, with
mean $\mu_b = 80$ before 'treatment' and $\mu_a = 82$ after treatment,
where the tendency toward increase for each subject is $D \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_d= 2, \sigma_d = 5).$ Now the most directly relevant data are the 'improvement scores' $X_{ai} - X_{bi} = D_i.$
We test $H_0: \mu_a - \mu_b = \mu_d = 0$ against $H_a: \mu_d \ne 0.$

*Test:* The test statistic is $T = \frac{\bar D}{S_d/\sqrt{n}}.$  We reject $H_0$ at the 5% level if $|T| > 2.064.$

```
qt(.975, 24)
[1] 2.063899
```

Again the issue is whether we can distinguish whether $\mu_d$ differs from $0$
above the noise represented by $\sigma_d = 5.$

*With data:* Fake data generated according
this this model with an average improvement of $\mu_d = 2$ is as follows:

```
set.seed(901); d = round(rnorm(25, 2, 5));  xb = round(rnorm(25, 80, 5));  xa = xb + d
summary(xb);  sd(xb)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  70.00   77.00   81.00   80.92   86.00   96.00 
[1] 5.929587
summary(xa);  sd(xa)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     66      77      84      83      87      99 
[1] 8.784456
summary(d); sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  -6.00    0.00    1.00    2.08    4.00   13.00 
[1] 4.698581
```

[image]

A paired t test on these data is essentially a one-sample t test on the differences: `t.test(d)` returns $T = 2.2134,$ which has $|T| > 2.064,$ so
we reject $H_0.$
[The P-value is p-value = 0.037, which also indicates rejection. The statement `t.test(xa, xb, pair=T)` produces essentially the same output.] So in this
particular case a paired design has enabled us to detect the effect. One can show that data from our model would reject $H_0$ about half of the time. In the
paired model the vectors `x_b` and `x_a` are ordinarily significantly correlated,
because $X_{bi}$ and $X_{ai}$ are both from the same ($i$th) subject; for
our data the sample correlation is about $r = 0.87,$ which is not consistent
with independence.

[image]

*Discussion:* With the paired design, the before-measurements have relatively large
variability. Especially dealing with human and animal subjects, we have to expect high
variability. (The after-measurements also have relatively large variability.) But in the paired design, each subject is its own sub-experiment,
and the random variable of interest is the change $D_i$ for each subject. Ordinarily, it is mostly the variability in the effect of the treatment
that matters in a paired design. (Granted, it can happen that different
subjects react to the treatment in surprisingly different ways.) So it is the (usually)
relatively small variance $\sigma_d$ that determines how easily we can
detect whether $\mu_d \ne 0.$

***Notes:*** (1) Whether a particular computation with two-sample or with paired data
happens to give a high or low P-value depends on the nature of the data.

(2) If paired data are incorrectly analyzed using a two-sample test, then the
advantage of pairing is ignored, and the P-value may be larger than it would
have been when correctly analyzed using a paired test.

(3) For two-sample data
with $n$  subjects in each group $(2n$ subjects altogether), the critical value of a pooled two-sample test will be based on $\nu = 2n-2$ degrees of freedom. For paired data with $2$ observations on each of $n$ randomly chosen subjects, an appropriate paired t test will have a critical value based on $\nu = n - 1$ degrees of freedom. Thus, at the 5% level with the same $n,$ the paired test will have  critical values with a (somewhat) smaller absolute value. As $\nu$ increases the 5% critical values decrease in absolute value to a minimum of $\pm 1.96.$

However in practice, you should never be comparing $\nu$ for running a two-sample test with $\nu$ for running a paired test on the same data. One analysis is correct and one is not. Oranges have thicker skins than apples, but if you're making applesauce that is an irrelevant observation. You won't be dealing with oranges.

Comment: Your very thorough explanation is much appreciated. I will need to spend some time with it to fully grasp what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of **critical value of *t*** which is, excepting your sample size, unrelated to your data.

Different *samples* will surely produce different *t* statistics. And of course, if you have the same sample size in group 1 as in group 2 (or in measurement 1 as in measurement 2), then the paired and unpaired *t* test statistics be *different* numbers for the same sample. However, the critical value of *t* is not a statistic drawn from your sample data. Rather it is a value of *t*—given your sample size/degrees of freedom, and preferred rate of making a type I error—that marks the threshold between "reject" and "fail to reject" the null hypothesis. We can know what this critical value of *t* is (given the sample size), because we have a theory describing the behavior of Student's *t* distribution, specifically with values of *t* that are *unlikely* to occur if the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: Not sure how you can say that the critical value of t is unrelated to everything but sample size. It's related to the difference between the sample mean and the test value and of course dependent upon the standard error. What am I missing?

Comment: @EricinNYC Nope: that is the *test statistic*, not the *critical value* of the test statistic's distribution under the null. If $\alpha=0.05$, $df=9$ (with a two-tailed test), then the critical value $t^{*}=2.26$ regardless of what my data are. If my test statistic $|t|≥2.26$, I reject, if $|t|<2.26$ I fail to reject.

Answer (score -1):

The general principle at work here is that dependent samples give you less information than independent samples.

So, with the same number of samples an experiment with independent samples will have more power than an otherwise identical experiment with dependent samples that targets the same estimand. Similarly,  an analysis that assumes independence of observations will generally have a lower p-value / smaller standard errors - but to do such an analysis, if the samples were dependent is an exercise in (self-) deception (as pointed out by Cornfield in 1978 and perhaps others before that).

On the other hand, if you have independent samples and can add a few more dependent ones, this will give you more information - just not as much as adding independent samples (but it may also be cheaper/easier/more feasible).

Comment: Much appreciated. Just a follow-up. You state that you have LESS information in a dependent sample design; information about what?

Comment: Most things really - i guess except for within patient variability. E.g. if you do a randomized experiment about an intervention, you get less about the treatment effect by repeatedly measuring the same subject under the same treatment than by measuring a completly new subject under the treatment.

Comment: You have this *exactly* backward: the unpaired (independent) *t* test has less power than the paired (dependent) *t* test because the dependency of paired samples reduces the variance of the estimates. The same holds true, for example, with repeated measures (dependent) oneway ANOVA which has far more power than the corresponding (independent) oneway ANOVA.

Comment: @Alexis Compare assessing 100 patients per group at baseline, week 11 and week 12, where we have the same treatment effect at week 11 and 12, and week 11 and 12 are correlated. Instead, measure 200 patients per group at baseline and week 12. Or just that without a baseline. Do you seriously think you have more power with the first approach?

Comment: @Alexis Of course, a paired t-test or ANCOVA with adjustment for baseline should have more power than one without previous information. However, an extra correlated assessment of the same thing is for most purpose worth less than another independent assessment.

Comment: @Björn Not sure which field you are in, but, for example, in epidemiology, repeated measures designs—designing dependence into the study—are considered worth more, not less, because, for example, no control is more like an individual assigned to treatment than that very same individual before they were treated (i.e. we account for within individual variance). Since the OP asked explicitly about *t* tests, my comment about the greater power with the paired vs lower power with the unpaired test seems apt.